# Knockout.js: Problems relecting changes to an array element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to make a knockout based application an I've run into a seemingly unsolvable problem: I'm making a UI for manipulating a list of event objects. The list of event objects is displayed in a main view, which contains a table of event objects, with a few properties that can be altered in the main view.

But because the event objects will contain complex data, like sub-arrays etc., I want to be able to open a modal view from the list of event objects, in order to do detailed editing of a single event object. The modal view is run from inside the same page as the main view, so I am able to use the same data model for both views.

I am able to edit properties in a single event object in the modal view, but the changes are not reflected in the main view, for some reason. When I iterate the event array, I can see that the array element in question has been changed. I try to execute the valueHasMutated method on the array (which is an observable array), but this has no effect. Would appreciate some good advice here. I've tried to compile a self contained HTML page which explains the problem better than words. But I'm afraid the code is a bit long. But here it is anyway:
    
    
    
        Knockout Test

```
<form id="photograph-form">
    <div class="row-fluid span12">
        <h4>Events</h4>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover span11 table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="span1">Delete</th><th class="span1">Edit</th><th class="span1">Type</th><th class="span1">Dating basis</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: events">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEvent"><i
                        class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                <td><a data-bind="click: $root.setCurrentEvent" href="#eventView" role="button"
                       data-toggle="modal">
                    <i class="icon-edit"></i></a></td>

                <td><select class="input-medium" data-bind="value: event_type,
                                   options: event_types,
                                   optionsValue: 'identifier',
                                   optionsText: 'name'"></select></td>
                <td><input class="input-medium" data-bind="value: foundation"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<p>Current item foundation: <span data-bind="text: currentEvent().foundation"></span></p>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#eventView" data-bind="click: $root.addEvent">New</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal window -->
<div id="eventView" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="eventLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true">×
        </button>
        <h3 id="eventLabel">Event</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="eventType">Event type</label>

        <select id="eventType" class="input-medium" data-bind="value: currentEvent().event_type,
                                   options: event_types,
                                   optionsValue: 'identifier',
                                   optionsText: 'name'"></select>
        <label for="eventFoundation">Dating basis</label>
        <input id="eventFoundation" class="input-medium"
               data-bind="value: currentEvent().foundation"/>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: $root.updateEvent">OK
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/knockout.js"></script>

<script>
    var event_types = [
        { identifier: "accession", name: "Accession" },
        { identifier: "other", name: "Other" },
        { identifier: "ownership", name: "Ownership" }
    ];

    var model = new ArtifactModel("photograph");
    model.history_description = ko.observable();
    model.events = ko.observableArray([
        { event_type: "accession", foundation: "Found"},
        { event_type: "ownership", foundation: "Museum"}
    ]);
    model.currentEvent = ko.observable({ event_type: "accession", foundation: "Found"});

    ko.applyBindings(model);


    function ArtifactModel(artifact_type) {
        var self = this;
        self.artifact_id = ko.observable();
        self.events = ko.observableArray();
        self.currentEvent = ko.observable();

        // Operations
        self.addEvent = function () {
            self.events.push({
                event_type: "",
                foundation: ""
            });
            self.currentEvent(self.events()[self.events().length - 1]);
        };

        self.setCurrentEvent = function(event) {
            self.currentEvent(event);
            console.log("Before: Event.foundation: " + self.currentEvent().foundation);
        };

        self.updateEvent = function(event) {
            for (var t = 0 ; t < event.events().length ; t++) {
                console.log("After: Event.foundation: " + event.events()[t].foundation);
            }
            event.events.valueHasMutated(); // No effect!
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because your `event` objects do not have observable properties themselves.  Try changing the event definition to something like this:

```
{
    event_type: ko.observable("accession"),
    foundation: ko.observable("Found")
}
```

You may need to make some other changes to account for the fact that these properties are now observable, but it will mean that changes made to the object from one location will be reflected in other locations.

Comment: A potential issue with this solution, is that the model and the event array will initially be populated using ajax. I'm not sure whether it will be possible to impose observable properties. But I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: The suggested solution works: Making the properties observable works when editing events added through the UI.
As for for events generated from ajax calls, it seems the ko.mapping.fromJS method automatically sets the properties to be observable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to have is to have array of objects with observable values. Then you would not need to do anything extra.

It would be helpful if you would have your demo in the http://jsfiddle.net/